# Extracting column range from text file via bash tool

Tags: string, bash, awk, split, multiple-columns

Assume a text file (`file1`) that contains multiple lines of alphabetic strings, each preceded by a short alphanumeric string that acts as a barcode. The alphabetic strings are all identic in length, the preceding alphanumeric ones are not. Alphabetic and alphanumeric strings are separated by a whitespace in each line.

```
$ cat file1
a1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
b27 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
c4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Assume a second file (`file2`) that contains information on a column range. This range is always smaller than the alphabetic string.

```
$ cat file2
2-13
```

I am trying to develop bash code that extracts the column range specified in `file2` from the alphabetic strings in `file1`, while maintaining the barcodes.

```
$ sought_command file1 file2
a1 bcdefghijklm
b27 bcdefghijklm
c4 bcdefghijklm
```

I am uncertain which bash power tool would be helpful in this regard, but presume that `awk` will be the tool that could do this.

*Note: I am aware that code in Python may be easiest to write regarding this task, which I did. However, I found my Python implementation to be unreasonably slow, as the alphabetic strings to be processed are tens of thousands of characters long. Thus, I am deliberately trying to solve this issue with a bash tool.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{start=$1;lgth=$2;next} {print $1, substr($2,start,lgth)}' FS='-' file2 FS=' ' file1
a1 bcdefghijklmn
b27 bcdefghijklmn
c4 bcdefghijklmn
```

or if the 2nd field is the end position rather than the length:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{start=$1;lgth=$2-$1+1;next} {print $1, substr($2,start,lgth)}' FS='-' file2 FS=' ' file1
a1 bcdefghijklm
b27 bcdefghijklm
c4 bcdefghijklm
```

Comment: Wow! To me, that is bash power at its finest. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks but that answer has nothing to do with bash. It's awk, a completely separate tool that can be called from any UNIX shell (bash, ksh, csh, sh, etc.) or from Windows. It just happens to come as standard with all UNIX installations. Use of bash or any other shell constructs would not be appropriate for your problem - see [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I just realized that your code acts as if the second number of `file2` were the length, not the stop position of the column range. To correct for the issue, I attempted to modify your command to `awk 'NR==FNR{start=$1;lgth=$(expr $2-$1);next} {print $1, substr($2,start,lgth)}' FS='-' file2 FS=' ' file1`. See the internal subtraction. However, my modification is not working. Would you have a suggestion for me?

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question what the file2 values meant. You really need to understand - **awk is not bash**. `$((stop-start))` and `$(expr $2-$1)` are bash syntax, not awk. In awk to subtract the value of one variable from the other you just do `stop-start`. It'd be more efficient of course to leave that part of the script alone and make the first part `NR==FNR{start=$1;lgth=$2-$1+1;next}` and I've updated my answer to show that. You can learn awk from the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thank you for your additional answer. It's clear now.

Comment: You're welcome. Going forward if/when trying to guess at awk syntax you'll have more success trying to emulate C syntax than bash (or any other shell) syntax since awk is essentially just a stripped-down C with extra functionality specific to manipulating text. And again - **awk is not bash!** :-).

Comment: I posted a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022297/extracting-column-ranges-and-reconstituting-matrix-via-awk). May I ask for your insightful suggestions once again?