# Extracting column ranges and reconstituting matrix via awk

Tags: string, awk, split, concatenation, multiple-columns

Assume a text file (`file1`) that contains *m* lines of alphabetic strings *S* (*S_1*, *S_2*, ..., *S_m*). Each *S* is preceded by a short alphanumeric string that acts as a barcode (here: *foo1*, *bar7*, *baz3*). The alphabetic strings *S* are all identical in length. Each *S* and its preceding barcode is separated by a whitespace.

```
$ cat file1
foo1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bar7 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
baz3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Assume a second file (`file2`) that contains *n* specifications of column ranges *R* (*R_1*, *R_2*, ..., *R_n*). The column ranges are on a single line and separated by whitespaces. Each *R_x* is smaller than *S*. The combined lengths of the ranges (i.e., *R_1* + *R_2* + ... + *R_n*) is also smaller than *S*. None of the ranges overlap or constitute a subset of each other.

```
$ cat file2
2-11 14-19 23-24
```

Following [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944398/3981290), I understand that I can extract the first range (i.e., *R_1*) of all *S* via the following *awk* command, while keeping the barcodes correctly assigned:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{start=$1;lgth=$2;next} {print $1, substr($2,start,lgth)}' FS='-' file2 FS=' ' file1
```

However, I am uncertain how to expand the *awk*-code to loop over all other ranges (here: *R_2* and *R_3*) and append each to the growing matrix.

```
$ sought_outcome
foo1 bcdefghijknopqrswx
bar7 bcdefghijknopqrswx
baz3 bcdefghijknopqrswx
```

**Edit:**
For better understanding, here is the sought output illustrated such that the concatenation points are emphasized by whitespaces:

```
     2-11       14-19  23-24
foo1 bcdefghijk nopqrs wx
bar7 bcdefghijk nopqrs wx
baz3 bcdefghijk nopqrs wx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue! without any validation checks!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {printf "%s", "key"; 
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                  {split($i,x,"-"); 
                   start[i]=x[1]; 
                   end[i]  =x[2]; 
                   printf "%s", FS $i}; 
                print ""; 
                next} 

               {printf "%s", $1; 
                for(i in start) printf "%s", FS substr($2,start[i],end[i]-start[i]+1); 
                print ""}' range file | 
  column -t


key   2-11        14-19   23-24
foo1  bcdefghijk  nopqrs  wx
bar7  bcdefghijk  nopqrs  wx
baz3  bcdefghijk  nopqrs  wx
```

or, without the header and splitting

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                 {split($i,x,"-"); start[i]=x[1]; end[i]=x[2]}; 
                  print ""; n=NF; next}
              {printf "%s", $1 FS; 
               for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s", substr($2,start[i],end[i]-start[i]+1); print ""}' range file   column -t                        

foo1 bcdefghijknopqrswx
bar7 bcdefghijknopqrswx
baz3 bcdefghijknopqrswx
```

**UPDATE**
However, perhaps easier with cut/paste

```
$ paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 file) <(cut -d' ' -f2 file | cut -c$(tr ' ' ',' <range))
foo1 bcdefghijknopqrswx
bar7 bcdefghijknopqrswx
baz3 bcdefghijknopqrswx
```

Comment: Oooh, extra +1 for the nice cut'n'paste. Maybe add `-d' '` to paste as well

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with turned out to be almost exactly the same as @karakfas 2nd script but I find the way he formats his code extremely hard to read so I figured I'd post this anyway:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        split($i,range,/-/)
        beg[i] = range[1]
        end[i] = range[2]
    }
    numRanges = NF
    next
}
{
    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for (i=1; i<=numRanges; i++) {
        printf "%s", substr($2,beg[i],(end[i]-beg[i])+1)
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
foo1 bcdefghijknopqrswx
bar7 bcdefghijknopqrswx
baz3 bcdefghijknopqrswx
```